# Label and description visibility in transaction history

Tags: bitcoin-core

When I send a bitcoin payment I provide **label** and **description** for a transaction.
Is it possible to see these values on blockchain.info (or somewhere else) ? 
Or this information is available for receiver only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're local to your own client.